# Fileuploader form submit event calling panel to show containing fileuploder i want to remove codes rewriting using loop in jquery for all file types

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

i want `fileuploader` to call another event/function on `fileuploader` file selection and  remove rewriting codes for each uploader

**css codes**

```
   #panel,#flip,#panel1,#panel2
    {
       padding:5px;
       text-align:center;
       background-color:#e5eecc;
       border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
    }
    #panel
    {
       padding:50px;
       display:none;
    }
    #panel1
    {
       padding:50px;
       display:none;
    }
    #panel2
    {
       padding:50px;
       display:none;
    }
```

**html codes**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
      <title></title>
      <style> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

           <form id="form1" runat="server" >           

        <div  id="flip">
             <input id="fileupload" type="file" />
        </div>
        <div id="panel">
         <input id="fileupload1" type="file" />
        </div>
        <div id="panel1">
           <input id="fileupload2" type="file" />
        </div> 

        <div id="panel2">
           <input id="fileupload3" type="file" />
        </div>**
```

**jquery codes**
codes for  fileuploader file selection event where i am selecting  file i want next file uploader to appear

```
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              $("#fileupload").change(function () {
                  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
                  if (regex.test($(this).val().toLowerCase())) {
                      if ($.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) <= 9.0) {
                          $("#panel").show();
                        //  $("#dvPreview")


    [0].filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = $(this).val();
                      }
                      else {
                          if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                              $("#panel").show();

                              var reader = new FileReader();
                             reader.onload = function (e) {

                              }

                          } else {
                              alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
                          }
                      }
                  } else {
                      alert("Please upload a valid image file.");
                  }
              });
          });
    </script>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
           $(function () {
               $("#fileupload1").change(function () {
                   var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
                   if (regex.test($(this).val().toLowerCase())) {
                       if ($.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) <= 9.0) {
                           $("#panel1").show();
                           //  $("#dvPreview")[0].filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = $(this).val();
                       }
                       else {
                           if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                               $("#panel1").show();

                               var reader = new FileReader();
                               reader.onload = function (e) {

                               }

                           } else {
                               alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
                           }
                       }
                   } else {
                       alert("Please upload a valid image file.");
                   }
               });
           });
    </script>
         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
             $(function () {
                 $("#fileupload2").change(function () {
                     var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
                     if (regex.test($(this).val().toLowerCase())) {
                         if ($.browser.msie && parseFloat(jQuery.browser.version) <= 9.0) {
                             $("#panel2").show();
                             //  $("#dvPreview")[0].filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = $(this).val();
                         }
                         else {
                             if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                                 $("#panel2").show();

                                 var reader = new FileReader();
                                 reader.onload = function (e) {

                                 }

                             } else {
                                 alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
                             }
                         }
                     } else {
                         alert("Please upload a valid image file.");
                     }
                 });
             });
    </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following JS code will help you . Modified the JS and used your HTML and CSS with few modification.

**JS**

```
   function validate_file()
   {

        if($("input[type^=file]").val() == '' || $("input[type^=file]").val() == null )
        {
            alert("Please upload file");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {   
        var count = $("input[type^=file]").length;

            var fileName = $('input[type^=file]:visible').val();
             alert($("input[type^=file]")[0].files[0].name);

                    if($('input[type^=file]:visible').val() != '' || $('input[type^=file]:visible').val() != null)
                    {
                            var ext = fileName.substr((fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
                            alert(ext);
                        if(ext == 'jpg' || ext == 'bmp' || ext == 'png')
                        {
                                alert("Valid file");
                                $("div[id^=panel]:visible").next().css('display','block');

                        }
                        else
                        {
                                alert("Uploaded file is invalid");
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('please select file to upload');
                        return false;
                    }

      }
        return false;
    }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[type^=file]").change(function(){
                validate_file();
            });
        });

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1"  >           
<div id="panel1" class="panel">
<input type="file" id="fileupload1"/>
</div>
<div id="panel2" class="panel">
<input type="file" id="fileupload2"/>
</div>
<div id="panel3" class="panel">
<input type="file" id="fileupload3"/>
</div>
<div id="panel4" class="panel">
<input type="file" id="fileupload4"/>
</div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
            <style type="text/css">
            #panel1,#panel2,#panel3,#panel4
{
   padding:5px;
   text-align:center;
   background-color:#e5eecc;
   border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel2
{
   padding:50px;
   display:none;
}
#panel3
{
   padding:50px;
   display:none;
}
#panel4
{
   padding:50px;
   display:none;
}
            </style>
```